# Which is the official nextcloud docker image vs. all-in-one?

Tags: docker, nextcloud

Up until now I am using the `nextcloud` docker image. However recently I noticed a note on the top of the readme, stating that it is not the officially supported image by Nextcloud.

They link to some `nextcloud/all-in-one` image. Looks like this image completely manages all necessary further nextcloud containers, which sounds neat on the first sight.
However reading the docs it has plenty of implications, e.g. no compatibility to nginx-proxy or possibility to change the default ports.

Do you guys have experience with this way of nextcloud installation and is it advisable to switch to the all-in-one image?
Is there a way to get it working with nginx-proxy? e.g. by placing another small nginx container in between nginx-proxy and the nextcloud?

Comment: Do you need official support?

Comment: No, don't need official support, it's a Family Cloud ;)

Comment: Then go with what you have if it works?